# Angular 2 Error

Tags: typescript, angular

I am having a Angular 2 error and it seems to be very difficult to find where the error resides. The error does not get detected during compile time but yet the browser presents it when trying to load up the page.

```
angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
        at __extends (http://localhost:3000/app/repository/award/award.service.js:7:72)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/repository/award/award.service.js:36:17)
        at execute (http://localhost:3000/app/repository/award/award.service.js:47:14)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

app/main.ts:

```
 ///<reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS])
  .then(success => console.log(`Bootstrap success`))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

repository:

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
// import { CONFIG } from '../shared/config';
import { IEntity } from './ientity';

@Injectable()
export abstract class Repository<T extends IEntity>
{
  protected url = null;

  constructor(protected _http: Http) {}

  add(entity: T) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let body = {
      name: entity.name
    };

    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic');

    return this._http
      .post(`${this.url}`, JSON.stringify(body), {
        headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  delete(entity: T) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic');

    return this._http
      .delete(`${this.url}/${entity.id}`, {
        headers: headers
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  list() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic');

    return this._http.get(`${this.url}`, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) =>
        <T[]>response.json().data
      )
      // .do(items => console.log(items))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  get(id: number) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic');

    return this._http.get(`${this.url}/${id}`, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => <T>response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  update(entity: T) {
    let headers = new Headers();

    let body = {
      name: entity.name
    };

    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic');

    return this._http
      .put(`${this.url}/${entity.id}`, JSON.stringify(body), {
        headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json())
      // .do(res => console.log(body))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

award.service:

```
import { Http } from 'angular2/http';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { CONFIG } from '../shared/config';
import { Repository } from '../core';
import { IAward } from './iaward';

@Injectable()
export class AwardService extends Repository<IAward>
{
  protected url = CONFIG.baseUrls.awards;

  constructor(protected _http: Http) {
    super(_http);
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us your app/main.ts

Comment: @DanielKucal please see above

Comment: Then let's start with the fact that you're putting `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in the bootstrap array, but it's not imported anywhere. Try `import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';` and let us know where that lands you.

Comment: @DanielKucal I made a mistake I must have thought I copied the whole file and didn't. I have updated it with the rest of it.

Comment: Show us `/app/repository/award/award.service` file

Comment: @acdcjunior please see above. Award.Service.ts inherits from abstract Repository.ts.

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using? Do you use `*.min.js` files?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I use "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17". I have not been minifying the files. I have type script files that get compiled down to javascript using gulp

Comment: Can you try without the polyfills? What browser did you test with?

Comment: I am using the newest version of chrome. When I try and comment out the pollyfills from the index page i get this error. Error: reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators
 Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js

Comment: Have you specified your service as a provider in the component in which you are using it or higher up the component tree?

Comment: I can reproduce this just by adding the following to my project: 

export class Subclass extends Base {} class Base {}

Comment: Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ge5gfckgXMp5ylUhKOEn - move the base class to be defined first, and no error. Seems like it might be related - but I am unable to reproduce in the multiple file scenario.

Comment: Thanks @James if you post your answer ill accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reproduced this by adding the following to my project:

```
export class Subclass extends Base {}
class Base {}
```

And then worked around the error by defining the base class first:

```
class Base {}
export class Subclass extends Base {}
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ge5gfckgXMp5ylUhKOEn - move the base class to be defined first, and no error. Seems like it might be related - but I am unable to reproduce in the multiple file scenario.

Comment: I believe this is due to the fact that unlike functions, [classes don't get hoisted in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Hoisting), so at the time you try to extend `Base`, that class doesn't actually exist yet. The spec says that this should lead to a ReferenceError, but since this code is being transpiled rather than using native classes, you get a more confusing error instead.